# How to reference self in a new javascript function?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to make a "Class" factory with Javascript so that I can create different types of objects.

Here is the function I'm using:

```
var Class = function(methods) {   
    var klass = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };  

    for (var property in methods) { 
       klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
    }

    if (!klass.prototype.initialize) klass.prototype.initialize = function(){};

    return klass;    
};
```

Then I can do:

```
var myObject = Class({
    initialize: function() { console.log(self);}
});
var createdObject = new myObject();
```

However, the console.log(self) is always referring to Window, and I'd like it to refer to the object itself.

I know this is a scope issue, but I'm confused on how to create a reference to the object?

I am trying to make a "Class" factory with Javascript so that I can create different types of objects.

Here is the function I'm using:

```
var Class = function(methods) {   
var klass = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};  

for (var property in methods) { 
   klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
}

if (!klass.prototype.initialize) klass.prototype.initialize = function(){};

return klass;
```

};

Then I can do:

```
var myObject = Class({
    initialize: function() { console.log(self);}
});
var createdObject = new myObject();
```

However, the console.log(self) is always referring to Window, and I'd like it to refer to the object itself.

I know this is a scope issue, but I'm confused on how to create a reference to the object?

For example, if I wanted to do:

```
var myObject = Class({
    initialize: function() { 
       $('#myDiv').click( function() {
           self.anotherFunction();
       });
    },

    anotherFunction: function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

I would need to be able to reference the "myObject" with self...

Comment: Try `this` instead of `self`?

Comment: `self` points to a global object, at least in webkit.

Comment: right...so how do i point to the current object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `self`. self will not be accessible to `initialize` function as it is defined outside the scope of `klass self`

Best option is define `self` inside each function as last solution I provided.

```
var myObject = Class({
    initialize: function() { console.log(this);}
});
```

OR

```
 var myObject = Class({
        initialize: function() { console.log(createdObject);}
    });
```

OR

```
var myObject = Class({
            initialize: function() { var self = this; console.log(self );}
        });
```

Comment: That's cool, but i need to save a reference to "this" somewhere so that I can use it inside the object in narrower scopes...for example in a jquery function or something...

Comment: createdObject  is same as your self. so instead of using self use createdObject.

Comment: lets say we add another enclosure to the initialize function like initialize: function() { $('#myDiv').click(function() { self.anotherFunction(); }); }

Comment: what's happening is im creating multiple instances of this type of object, but the click events are getting confused between them. the "self" is changing each time to the last instance created.

Comment: I got your problem. see my last solution. define self inside initialize function and use it.  initialize: function() { var self = this; $('#myDiv').click(function() { self.anotherFunction(); }); }